# How to create a hub and spoke with 500 spokes in Azure

Tags: azure, networking, azure-virtual-network, topology, virtual-network

I want to create a hub and spoke topology with more than 500 spoke virtual networks in Azure.

However, there are a few limitations.

1. A virtual network can peer to up to 500 virtual network via peering.
2. A route table can have up to 400 routes.

How can I scale up this? Also, how do you overcome the route table limit (400) before hitting the peering limit (500), say in a case you have 4xx spoke virtual networks?

Comment: While I understand your intent with the networking peering and you hitting the limit, I don't quite understand how you hit the limit with the route table routes? Can you provide more details on how the routes would be used and why you need more than 400? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, if the VNet peering number is reaching the max limitation of 500, you can upvote [this feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking/suggestions/40522381-increase-vnet-peering-limit-of-500)(Increase VNET Peering Limit of 500) to enhance it or raise a new request about route table limit like [this](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking/suggestions/42127603-increase-expressroute-gateway-related-200-routes-b).

Currently, it seems there is no better solution to overcome it. You may consider optimizing the network structure to reduce the peering numbers by using a [vnet-to-vnet gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-vnet-vnet-resource-manager-portal) connection.